# MIPS find lowest value?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have tried following code and for first two integer numbers it is working fine. but when we take smallest number in 3rd prompt, it will not taken as smallest number. this is my code. where that mistake i made.(sorry for my bad English)

thanks a lot..

```
    .text
.align 2 
.globl main 

main: 
# this program prints out the lowest value of three numbers input 

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt1 
syscall 

li $v0, 5 # read keyboard into $v0 (number x is number to test) 
syscall 
move $t0,$v0 # first number in $t0 

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt2 
syscall 

li $v0, 5 # read keyboard into $v0 (number x is number to test) 
syscall 
move $t1,$v0 # second number in $t1 

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt3 
syscall 

li $v0, 5 # read keyboard into $v0 (number x is number to test) 
syscall 
move $t2,$v0 # third number in $t2 

blt $t1, $t0, L1 
move $t1, $t0 # smallest number in $t1 

blt $t2, $t1, L1 
move $t2, $t1

L1: 
li $v0, 4 # print answer 
la $a0, answer 
syscall 

li $v0, 1 # print integer function call 1 
move $a0, $t1 # integer to print 
syscall 

end: jr $ra 

.data 
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the first number " 
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the second number " 
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter the third number " 
answer: .asciiz "\nThe smallest number is "
```

Answer (score 1):

The bit where you try to select the smallest number:

```
blt $t1, $t0, L1 
move $t1, $t0 # smallest number in $t1 

blt $t2, $t1, L1 
move $t2, $t1

L1:
```

You only have one label, so if the first branch is followed, you skip the compare with the 3rd number entirely.

You would need something more like:

```
blt $t1, $t0, L1 
move $t1, $t0 # smallest number in $t1 

L1: 

blt $t2, $t1, L2
move $t2, $t1

L2:
```

Comment: dear sir..same solution after this modification.. L1:
blt $t2, $t1, L2 
move $t2, $t1

L2: 
li $v0, 4 # print answer 
la $a0, answer 
syscall

Comment: well you're also not saving any of those registers across calls, but as you haven't actually said what result you're getting, it's tough to answer.